# Jquery checked unchecked transition not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, jquery-events

I have an HTML and jQuery `onclick` event like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.switch-input', function(e) {
  $("#switch-2").attr('checked', !$('#switch-2').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="switch" class="switch">
  <input id="switch-2" type="checkbox" class="switch-input  cekirajMe">
  <label for="switch-2" class="switch-label">Switch</label>
</div>
```

But for some reason this doesn't works... I want to make a smooth transition (ie. checkbox checked or unchecked) when the button/label is presesd.

Can someone help me out?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what transition?

Comment: what transition you want

Comment: "It doesn't work" surely means that your checkbox doesn't get checked ever. "For some reason" is because you click it, which does check it, then your code inverts this, immediately unchecking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#switch', function(e) {
  $("input",this).attr('checked', $('input',this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Your logic seemed a bit strange, since `.switch-input` and `#switch-2` is the same element.

But honestly you don't even need jquery to do this, check the demo, I've removed the jquery and it works just fine.

**Demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="switch" class="switch">
  <input id="switch-2" type="checkbox" class="switch-input  cekirajMe">
  <label for="switch-2" class="switch-label">Switch</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this do, besides checking the checkbox?

Comment: What works? It's just a checkbox being checked... Why load jQuery just to have the default checkbox behaviour??

Comment: @JeremyThille there will be a logic inside this when the checkbox is checked... It was just the beginning part of the jquery code...

Answer (score 0):

You are asking JavaScript to do the thing that HTML does by default for you using it's own property.

So by the time it gets to `$("#switch-2").attr('checked', !$('#switch-2').is(':checked'));` it changes the value which was already changed by the default behavior of HTML and unchecked checkbox appears unchecked but actually it's value got changed back to unchecked by the line highlighted above.

```js
var i= 0;
$(document).on('click', '.switch-input', function(e) {alert('i'+ ++i+$("#switch-2:checked").length);
  //$("#switch-2").attr('checked', !$('#switch-2').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="switch" class="switch">
  <input id="switch-2" type="checkbox" class="switch-input  cekirajMe">
  <label for="switch-2" class="switch-label">Switch</label>
</div>
```

Now that you know what was causing the issue, you don't actually need the click event listener and jQuery for this as this what the HTML check boxes are supposed to do as their default behavior.